# Is pyomo equality expression commutative?

Tags: python, solver, pyomo, ipopt

Here's a constraint defined by a function:

```
def my_constraint(model, j):
    a = sum(model.variable_1[i, j] for i in model.i) + sum(model.variable_2[o, j] for o in model.o if o != j)
    b = model.variable_3[j]
    # Apparently, the order matters !?
    return a == b
    # return b == a

model.my_constraint = pe.Constraint(model.j, rule=my_constraint)
```

I assumed the order of the terms of the equality wouldn't matter but if I switch them, I get different results.

I don't know how to get to the bottom of this.

The generated .nl files differ slightly but I'm in a dead end as I don't know how to interpret them.

#### Investigating .nl files

Two thee-line sets have a sign difference.

File 1:

```
[...]
24 1
32 -1
35 1
J78 3
25 1
33 -1
34 1
[...]
```

File 2:

```
[...]
24 -1
32 1
35 -1
J78 3
25 -1
33 1
34 -1
[...]
```

When feeding both files to ipopt, I get "infeasible" with file 1 and a solution with file 2. If I edit file 1 to change the signs in either the first or the second three-line set, I get convergence with the same results as file 2.

So the order in the equality of the expression should not matter, but when changing it, I get, in the .nl file, a sign difference that does matter.

#### Simple example demonstrating how the order of the terms affects the .nl file

```
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Set, Var, Constraint, Objective
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = ConcreteModel()

model.i = Set(initialize=['I1'])
model.j = Set(initialize=['J1'])

model.v1 = Var(model.i, model.j)
model.v2 = Var(model.i, model.j)
model.v3 = Var(initialize=0, bounds=(0, None))

def c1(model, i, j):
    #return model.v2[i, j] == model.v1[i, j]
    return model.v1[i, j] == model.v2[i, j]
model.c1 = Constraint(model.i, model.j, rule=c1)

def objective_rule(model):
    return model.v3
model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule)

opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.solve(model, keepfiles=True)
```

Depending of the order of the terms in constraint c1, I don't get the same .nl file.

More specifically, both files are identical except for two lines:

```
g3 1 1 0    # problem unknown
 3 1 1 0 1  # vars, constraints, objectives, ranges, eqns
 0 0 0 0 0 0    # nonlinear constrs, objs; ccons: lin, nonlin, nd, nzlb
 0 0    # network constraints: nonlinear, linear
 0 0 0  # nonlinear vars in constraints, objectives, both
 0 0 0 1    # linear network variables; functions; arith, flags
 0 0 0 0 0  # discrete variables: binary, integer, nonlinear (b,c,o)
 2 1    # nonzeros in Jacobian, obj. gradient
 0 0    # max name lengths: constraints, variables
 0 0 0 0 0  # common exprs: b,c,o,c1,o1
C0
n0
O0 0
n0
x1
2 0
r
4 0.0
b
3
3
2 0
k2
1
2
J0 2
0 -1    # The other file reads   0 1
1 1     #                        1 -1
G0 1
2 1
```

When solving, I get the same results. Probably because the example is rubbish.

Comment: In my own experience, switching RHS with LHS doesn't do a difference. I can't really help (maybe others can) but I would suggest to print your expression to look at what is happening. This can be done, in your case with `print(str(sum(model.variable_1[i, j] for i in model.i) + sum(model.variable_2[o, j] for o in model.o if o != j)) + ' == ' + str(model.variable_3[j]))`. Add it in your constraint definition function. Be careful to remove this line after your tests since it may considerably slow your program when printed lines are long.

Comment: Thanks @V.Brunelle If this is not a known issue, then I guess I'll have to provide a minified example to narrow down the search. I did try to print everything I could, and out of my memory it read SumExpression and Variable.

Comment: This is strange, it should print the whole line of your constraint expression, instead of printing only things like "SumExpression" or "Variable". I hope I gave you a working line. The goal was to print the expression that will be read by Pyomo. The output would have looked like "x[1,0] + x[2,0] +y[1,0] + y[2,0] == z[0]", supposing j=0

Comment: That was just out of my memory. Perhaps I didn't print the right thing. Print is my debug technique of choice so I think I printed everything I could but I may have missed something.

Comment: @V.Brunelle you're right, I get `EqualityExpression` and such when I print `(type(expression))`, otherwise, I get an output similar to what you expect. `print(a ==b)` and `print(b == a)` print what I expect so I'm still stuck. I asked on [GH](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/794).

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical explanation is that you're seeing alternative optimal solutions.  It's entirely possible, depending on the problem formulation, that you've got more than one solution that has the optimal objective value.  What order you get these in is going to be sensitive to the order of the constraints. If you're using an LP solver you ought to be able to ask it to give you all of the optimal solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I have an example where the solver finds a solution in one case and not in the other. Anyway, I don't understand why the order of the terms in the equality affects the way the problem is described in the .nl file, for instance. I'm OOO for the end of the year. I'll try to submit a minified case.